# Find generating function for the following conditions:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

$a_n=$ $2^{n+1}$ for $n:3|n$

$a_n=$ $0$ for the rest

So theres what I tried to do:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^{n}=2*z^0+0*z^1+0*z^2+2^4z^3+0*z^4+0*z^5+2^7z^6+...2^{k+1}z^k$$

$$2^{k+1}z^k=b^k$$

$$\frac{b^{k+1}}{b^k}$$

$$\frac{2^{k+2}z^{k+1}}{2^{k+1}z^{k}}=4z$$

$$q=4z$$
$$W_0=(4z)^2$$
$$A(z)=\frac{4^{z}}{1+(4z)^2}$$

Is this the right answer?

Comment: $3 \mid 0$ is $\displaystyle\color{red}{\texttt{true}}$ !!!.

Answer (score 1):

With $\displaystyle\left\vert z\right\vert < {1 \over 2}$,
$\displaystyle\quad\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}2^{3n + 1}\, z^{3n} =
2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left[\left(2z\right)^{3}\right]^{n} =\
\bbox[#ffd,10px,border:1px groove navy]{2 \over 1 - \left(2z\right)^{3}}$

Comment: Or explained with less notation, the series is a geometric series: $2 + 2^4z^3 + 2^7z^6+\cdots = 2+2(8z^3)+2(8z^3)^2+\cdots$. The first term is $2$ and the common ratio is $8z^3$, so the sum is $\displaystyle{ 2\over{1-8z^3}}$.

Comment: @SteveKass Fine. Thanks.